# How can I effectively use floats in equals()?

Tags: java, equals

I have the following immutable HSL class that I use to represent a colour and aide in calculations on RGBA colours with a little more finesse.

```
public class HSL {
  protected final float hue;
  protected final float saturation;
  protected final float lightness;

  public HSL(float hue, float saturation, float lightness) {
    this.hue = hue;
    this.saturation = saturation;
    this.lightness = lightness;
  }

  // [snip] Removed some calculation helper functions

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "HSL(" + hue + ", " + saturation + ", " + lightness + ")";
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return
        37 * Float.floatToIntBits(hue) +
        37 * Float.floatToIntBits(saturation) +
        37 * Float.floatToIntBits(lightness);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null || !(o instanceof HSL)) {
      return false;
    }

    HSL hsl = (HSL)o;
    // We're only worried about 4 decimal places of accuracy. That's more than the 24b RGB space can represent anyway.
    return
        Math.abs(this.hue - hsl.hue) < 0.0001f &&
        Math.abs(this.lightness - hsl.lightness) < 0.0001f &&
        Math.abs(this.saturation - hsl.saturation) < 0.0001f;
  }
}
```

While I don't foresee using this particular class in a `HashMap` or similar as it's an intermediary between a similar `RGBA` class which uses `int`s for it's internal storage, I'm somewhat concerned about the general case of using floats in equality. You can only make the epsilon for comparison so small, and even if you could make it arbitrarily small there are many `float` values that can be represented internally in multiple ways leading to different values returned from `Float.floatToIntBits`. What is the best way to get around all this? Or is it not an issue in reality and I'm just overthinking things?

Comment: It seems that your `equals` semantically means `closeTo`. Why not name it that way and use it instead of `equals`?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin: While I agree in general, there are some cases like this where the representation gets in the way of reality. In this case, if something has a hue that is 0.000001 different, that's a rounding error not an actual difference.

Comment: I mean that outside of collection classes you can use any method name on your classes to compare them, you do not have to call the method `equals` or `compareTo`.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin: My point was that you're arguing semantics and the semantics of the situation is that they are in fact equal, not close to which is why I like Duncan's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers do a great job of explaining why your current design may cause problems. Rather than repeat that, I'll propose a solution.

If you care about the accuracy only to a certain number of decimal places (it appears 4), you could multiply all incoming `float` values by 10,000 and manage them as `long` values. Then your equality and hashcode calculations are exact.

I assume you've omitted the getters from your class for brevity. If so, ensure your Javadocs clearly explain the loss of precision that will occur when passing a `float` into your class constructor and retrieving it from a getter.

Comment: this is the simplest and best option so far.

Comment: @Duncan, Actually, there are no getters, just about a half dozen different calculation functions which return a new HSL or convert to a RGBA value so this sort of solution makes even more sense in this case. An alternative would be converting to ints as you describe purely for the purposes of `equals()`/`hashCode()`.

Comment: @MatthewScharley Regarding your latter point, would there be a risk that two `HSL`s would be "equal", yet the minor differences in their `float` values result in a different `HSL` result, following a string of calculations? If so, I'd vote you store the values as `int`s right from the offset.

Answer (score 1):

This definition of equals() is not transitive. It really shouldn't be called equals(). This and the hashCode() issue would most likely silently bite when used in the Collections API. Things like HashSet would not work as expected and methods like remove(). For purposes here you should test for exact equality.

Comment: "This definition of equals() is not transitive." I think this is the actual issue with any implementation like this. `equals` needs to be transitive to make any implementation of `hashCode()` make sense beyond `return 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct to be concerned about the general case of `hashCode()` diverging heavily from `equals()`.

The violation of the general convention that hashes of two "equal" objects should have the same `hashCode()` will most likely lead to all sorts of unexpected behavior if this object is used in the future.

For starters, any library code that makes the usual assumption that unequal hashCodes implies unequal objects will find a lot of unequal objects where it should have found equal objects, because the `hashCode` check usually comes first, for performance.

Answer (score 0):

`hashcode` is like defining a bucket that an object should reside in. With hashing, if an object is not in its right bucket, you cannot find that with the `equals()` method.

Therefore, all the `equal` objects must reside in the same bucket (i.e., their `hashcode()` method should return the same result) or the results would be unpredictable.

Comment: it is clear to him the purpose and seriousness of equals deviating from hashcode, he seems to be more bothered about that inorder to implement equals, he is forced to do floating point arithmetic which can be unpredictable sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to weaken the `hashCode` implementation to prevent it from violating contract with `equals` - I mean ensure that when `equals` returns true, then `hashCode` returns the same value but not necessarily the other way around.

Comment: This is complicated a lot by the fact that as SeanOwen mentioned, this implementation of `equals()` isn't transitive meaning there's no line to define an implementation of hashCode on and the only real solution would be to return a static value.

Comment: It would solve contract issues, but it would be a poor implementation.  I think you could try using the same delta you use in `equals` and then round up and use for example ceiling of float values in `hashCode` - or something like that.

Comment: Which is for all intents and purposes what Duncan is proposing, only by removing the uncertainty altogether by not using floats in the first place.